# Unselect first row search in ng2-smart-table

Tags: css, angular, sass, hover

Is there any way to unselect the first row in [ng2-smart-table](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/)? Note once it is loaded the first row always has the `selected` class. The thing is I want to add a `hover` in a`.scss` file to change the background, but it never changes the first one, but all of the reamining rows can change background.

```
tbody {
    tr:hover {
        background: #209e91;
    }
}
```

Look at [this](http://akveo.com/ng2-admin/#/pages/tables/smarttables) example, the first row has a background when it is loaded.

EDIT:

Looking at the source it seems to select it arbitrary:

**data-set.ts**

```
protected willSelect: string = 'first';
  ...
  select(): Row {
    if (this.getRows().length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    if (this.willSelect) {
      if (this.willSelect === 'first') {
        this.selectFirstRow();
      }
      if (this.willSelect === 'last') {
        this.selectLastRow();
      }
      this.willSelect = '';
    } else {
      this.selectFirstRow();
    }

    return this.selectedRow;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `!important` to override the the styling from the `selected` class

```
tbody tr:hover {
    background: #209e91 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add selectedRowIndex: -1 to your table settings like this

```
tableSettings = { 
  hideSubHeader: true, 
  mode: 'external', 
  selectedRowIndex: -1
};
```

Source: https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/502#issuecomment-876178945

This prevents to select the first row by default.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but having the same issue today has put me into search and found that was the "real" solution.